# Fullcalendar scheduler timeline 12 months unique slots view with appended column

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using the Scheduler Timeline view of Fullcalendar limited to one slot per month (12 slots for the current year), but I need a resource column (or a custom column) appended to the right side of the scheduler. Is possible to append a custom column to the view? I saw that currently is possible to append resource columns to the left side of the Calendar, but not to the right.

```
|         | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sept | Oct | Nov | Dec | Custom Column |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Content |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |      |     |     |     |     Text      |
```

Comment: "I need a resource column (or a custom column) appended to the right side of the scheduler"...for what purpose exactly? That would help us to understand what you need. Also, what version of fullCalendar are you using?

Comment: The resource priority is located at the end of the resource row (after the months slots). This element will be showing a badge or custom HTML depending on this property. I'm using fullcalendar-scheduler@5.3.1 and a valid license that I have just bought.

Comment: There's no built-in way to add another column on the right hand side currently (perhaps you could make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) for it and/or [contribute the code yourself](https://fullcalendar.io/contributing)). But you can add extra HTML content and columns to the left-hand side using the existing options. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-display and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view for details. Perhaps that would be sufficient to meet your basic requirement - it will just as visible on the left as on the right (if not more so).

Comment: Yes, I have put right now on the left hand side, but I didn't know if there is any option to put on the right hand side. I will evaluate the possibility to contribute with this feature.